# Postgresql 9.2 installation on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.2

For installing `postgresql 9.2` I followed this url : http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-postgresql-9-2-on-ubuntu-server-using-ppa.html

But at the end of installation output is like :

```
Setting up postgresql-common (140~precise) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Adding user postgres to group ssl-cert
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
Setting up postgresql-9.2 (9.2.4-0ppa1~precise) ...
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

  pg_createcluster 9.2 main --start

or a similar command (see 'man pg_createcluster').
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode.
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
```

And when I tried to start postgresql, it gives following error :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_MESSAGES = "en_IN.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
 * No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your system locale configuration is messed up. Your `LC_MESSAGES` is set to `en_IN.UTF-8` but `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8` which is weird and inconsistent. Did you set `LC_MESSAGES` in your `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment` or something?

You really should `dpkg-reconfigure locales`. See [how to select and generate locales in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LocaleConf).

Once you've fixed your locale setup, you can use the `pg_wrapper` command `pg_createcluster 9.2 main --start` as suggested by the error to create the cluster. After that, starting the service will work.

Comment: Before this I installed SDK6 but it didn't gave any error. Then why postgresql gave porblem?

Comment: @NareshJ What is "SDK6"? Do you perhaps mean "the OpenJDK 6 SDK"? The answer is that some programs don't mind so much if your locale configuration is completely broken. PostgreSQL does. **You need to re-generate your locales** so that the locale data for `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_IN.UTF-8` is actually present.

Comment: Hey thank you, I resolved problem by completedly removing postgres and then installed `language-pack-en-base` and then installed postgresql again. It worked. Thank you again for exactly pointing the error. :)

Answer (score 27):

I tried all of the solutions that I could find, but in the end this post sorted it:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1720356

Basically, add the language you want to /etc/environment. In my case:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Then added this to the end of the file:

```
LC_ALL="en_US.utf-8"
```

Then reboot the server

```
sudo reboot
```